# Input type="date" thymeleaf

Tags: java, hibernate, date, input, thymeleaf

I need to add date to my entity and let the user set it in web form.
This field needs to have today's date filled in by default.

```
1. <input type="date" value="2016-08-01">
```

shows correct date setted for default

```
2. <input type="date" th:value="${startDate}">
```

shows date picker without any value (note: String startDate = "2016-08-01";)

```
3. <input type="date" th:field="${startDate}">
```

generates 400 error (Bad request) (note: Date startDate = new Date();)

So, question is: how to use thymeleaf for input date?

- can I use Date() datatype for input and store such data?
- how I need to set "th:field" in  form?
- how I need to set "th:value" in same form?

My controller(s):

```
@RequestMapping("/project_new")
public String createProject(Model model) {
    Project project = new Project ();
    List<Role> roles = mRoleService.findAll();

    project.setStart(new Date());

    model.addAttribute("page_title", "create project");
    model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
    model.addAttribute("statuses", Status.values());
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    return "project_new";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/project_new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createProject(@ModelAttribute Project project, Model model) {
    // Fill id field for project.rolesNeeded
    mRoleService.setRolesId(project.getRolesNeeded());
    project.fixCollaboratorsAndRoles();

    mProjectService.save(project);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

My template:

```
<form th:action="@{/project_new}" method="post" th:object="${project}">
  <div class="project-list single">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" required="true" th:placeholder="*{name}" th:value="*{name}" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <textarea rows="5" id="description" type="text"  required="true" th:placeholder="*{description}" th:value="*{description}" th:field="*{description}"/>

    <label for="date-started">Date started:</label>
    <input type="date" th:value="${project.start}" th:field="${project.start}" id="date-started"/>

    <div>
      <label for="project_status">Project Status:</label>
      <div class="custom-select">
        <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
        <select th:field="*{status}" id="project_status">
          <option th:each="s : ${statuses}" th:value="${s}" th:text="${s}">Active</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="roles-collaborators">
    <ul class="checkbox-list">
      <li th:if="${role.name} ne 'Undefined'" th:each="role : ${roles}">
      <input type="checkbox"  th:value="${role}" th:field="${project.rolesNeeded}" class="checkbox"/>
      <span th:text="${role.name}" th:value="${role}" class="checkbox">Developer</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
    <a th:href="@{/}" class="button button-secondary">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Project entity:

```
@Entity
public class Project {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size (min = 3)
private String name;

@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String description;

@Column
private Status status;

@Column
private Date start;

@ManyToMany
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Role> rolesNeeded;

@ManyToMany
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Collaborator> collaborators;

public Date getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(Date start) {
    this.start = start;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the controller methods for your GET and POST actions and also the thymeleaf form?

Comment: Sure, added it to question

Comment: Please include the "form" element in the template and the Project class with the property "start" and the get and set methods for it.

Comment: Done, added <form> and Project class with getters/setters

Comment: Can you confirm the exact error code you are getting from your browser? Which browser is it?

Comment: 400 error code, browser Chrome

Comment: I am getting a 405 instead with my project configuration, so I am unable to test your code in the same conditions at this very moment, but from what I can see, you need to change your "th:value" and "th:field" attributes from your template for the date value from "${project.start}" to "*{start}".

Comment: Can you post the error log

Comment: There is no any logs messages, just after I'm posting form, only error message "400 Error", and no new records in project table.

Comment: Field error in object 'project' on field 'startDate': rejected value [2016-08-03]; codes [typeMismatch.project.startDate,typeMismatch.startDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [project.startDate,startDate]; arguments []; default message [startDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'startDate';

Comment: so <input type="date"> input String, not Date?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Taking a look at the comment with the error log it seems to be a conversion problem between `String` to `java.util.Date`. After searching for a while in the Thymeleaf GitHub I saw two issues which can explain how to proceed in this case:

- Discussion of the conversion including date in [this issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/19).
- Implementation of the conversion is explained [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/223).

From the last point, I added an annotation to the start date of your project class:

```
// This is "org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat"
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date start;
```

And after that, I was able to receive the date in your controller POST method.

Take into account you also need to change your `th:value` and `th:field` attributes from your template for the date value from `${project.start}` to `*{start}`, as I wrote in the comments, as you did for the `name` and `description` fields.

Comment: Thanks, it works! (i mean @DateTimeFormat). No need to change ${project.start} to *{start}, because its simple the same, I just prefer "full name" syntax :)

Comment: Just be careful then with the full syntax. If you are, for example, refactoring your code and change the "project" var name you need to change also the "${project.start}" and all the other full syntax occurences; this won't happen if you use the "*{field}" way.

Comment: To make all dates return that format, you can use WebMvcConfigurer.registry.addFormatterForFieldType(Date.class, new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"))

Answer (score 3):

Use String instead of Date:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private String fromDate;
```

Comment: You can still use Date type. By adding the @DateTimeFormat annotation alone will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date date;
```

controller class

```
pNow.setDate(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date start;
```

> This Annotation get the current year date and month . If you want to
> show current date in web page you can use this simple tag

```
th:attr="max=${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
```

Answer (score 0):

One common issue is that the date format expected by html form/datepicker is not the same as the spring default date format. This causes the form datetime-local input to show up as blank even when the value attribute is populated.

You can set the below values in `application.properties` to rectify this:

```
spring.mvc.format.date-time=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
spring.mvc.format.date=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
spring.mvc.format.time=HH:mm:ss
```

An additional benefit is that date strings in json responses are not affected by this property.