# Date from thymeleaf is always sent null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

this is my html form:

```html
<form ui-jp="parsley" th:action="@{/users/created}" th:object="${userCreateDto}" method="post">
    <div class="row m-b">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Valid From</label>
                <input type='date' class="form-control" th:field="*{validFrom}" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Valid To</label>
                <input type='date' class="form-control" th:field="*{validTill}" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/created", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processCreateUsers(@ModelAttribute UserCreateDto userCreateDto, BindingResult error) {
    log.info("Creating users with this input :"+ userCreateDto.toString());
    this.userService.createUser(userCreateDto);
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

And this is the DTO

```
public class UserCreateDto {

    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String password;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date validFrom;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date validTill;
}
```

Here Date is `java.sql.Date`

Also, when I import through a JSON file, where I have an array of users - I am able to run this successfully.

When I run it through view, I get the values of `validFrom` and `validTill` as null.

Also, when I check the form data after clicking submit - All of the required inputs are set properly. Event the Date parameters are set there.

This is when I print BindingResult error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date' for property 'validFrom'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date] for value '2017-12-10'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.joda.time.DateTime] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Date]
```

What am I missing here?

Note: java.util.Date works!

Comment: If you print out `BindingResult error`, what does it say?

Comment: Added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your form needs to have a bean in which it can bind those parameters.  You can use `@GetMapping` (and `@PostMapping`) as a shorthand.

```
@GetMapping("/theHtmlFormInYourQuestion")
public String createUsers(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("userCreateDto", new UserCreateDto());
    return "theHtmlFormInYourQuestion";
}
```

And your form action should use `created` instead of `users/created` since that's what your Java code shows (unless you're doing something else that's not posted in your question).

Comment: I've given @RequestMapping("users") for the controller. So, I am good with that. And, yes I already have a @GetMapping for this. And it does exactly as mentioned in your answer. But, still there is some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change `input type='date'...` to `input type='text'...` in your HTML.

If you need styling on the input, try to choose one of the available date pickers.

There is a specific issue with Thymeleaf and input type `Date` which is explained in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693971/input-type-date-thymeleaf).

Comment: The change should be the HTML input field from `type='date'` to `type='text'`. Your DTO seems just fine.

Comment: But, then it doesn't ensure that the next datepicker I use would give me correct value.

Comment: I do not think that is accurate. Datepickers allow you to specify the format of the input. As long as you have the format matching with the field in the DTO, you should be good.

Comment: I am able to get the format that I mentioned in the DTO using input='date'. However, I tried using bootstrap-datepicker, and it's the same issue. I still have null in the dto. And I checked the format from the form post parameters, and it has the format that I need at the backend.

Comment: I've added the output of BindingResult error in the question.

Comment: Could you try changing the date field in the DTO to `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`

Comment: Yeah, I did that before. I am using a json file where I have array of users to populate some users. When I use java.util.Date, that code breaks.

Comment: This is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762941/gson-fromjson-not-parsing-date-fields