# Gson.fromJson() not parsing Date fields

Tags: java, spring

I am executing a CommandLineRunner which takes input file (json) and convert it to dto for further processing.

```
List<UserCreateDto> users = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("user.json").getInputStream()), new TypeToken<List<UserCreateDto>>() {
                }.getType());
```

the json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "username": "user2",
    "firstName": "userfirst2",
    "lastName": "userlast2",
    "password": "userpass2",
    "validFrom": "2017-01-01",
    "validTill": "2020-01-01"
  },
  {
    "username": "user1",
    "firstName": "userfirst",
    "lastName": "userlast",
    "password": "userpass",
    "validFrom": "2017-01-01",
    "validTill": "2020-01-01"
  }]
```

The dto is fairly simple. Just one thing added

```
@DateTimeFormatter(format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
private Date validFrom;

@DateTimeFormatter(format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
private Date validTill;
```

And here Date is java.util.Date

However, when I run that code, I don't get `validFrom` and `validTo` in the users List. 
All of the values of `validFrom` and `validTill` is null.

What am I missing here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the date format on the `gson` instantiation itself

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").create();
```